# "expression is not assignable" when trying to assign a value to an element of an array of arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, expression

I created the following:

```
//main.cpp

const int size = 3;

int field[size][size] = {{0}};
int (*pfield)[size] = field;
```

A class of mine wants to set a value within a function:

```
//userInputs.cpp

int UserInputs::setValue(int (*field)[3], int x, int y) {

...


((*field)[x] + y) = value;

...

}
```

And it causes the following error:

```
src/userInputs.cpp:15:26: error: expression is not assignable
                        ((*field)[x] + y) = value;
```

As far as my understanding goes should `((*field)[x] + y) = value;` give me access to the to the value. Obviously, that's not the case and my issue is me not really understanding what went wrong. Not really experienced in C++ and pointers.

I appreciate any answers and/or explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you break down `((*field)[x])+y` you can see why it's unassignable.

C expressions are roughly read inside out so we start with `(*field)`, which is the same as `field[0]`, then tack on `[x]` and you have `field[0][x]`, which is still an l-value (assignable, i.e., can be on the left hand side of an `=`).  Then tack on the `+ y` and you have `field[0][x] + y`, which is now `y` added to the value at `field[0][x]` so is now an r-value (not assignable).

If you want to fix it and keep the form roughly the same, the * needs to move out of the `(())`.  That is, `*(field[x]+y) = value;`  Or more simply as `field[x][y] = value;`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Now I feel stupid haha. But yeah overthinking at it’s finest on my side